# Override the base control class in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml

What options are there to replace the class specified in xaml with another subclass?

For example, if I define a Button, assuming that MyControl derives from Button, in xaml:

```
<Button />
```

It would instantiate my own control as if the user specified:

```
<namespace:MyControl/>
```

The reason for this is to avoid people having to know what controls are overriding the default ones in the application. I thought overriding the control template would be sufficient however we had to override the measure and arrange in the custom control.

Comment: I want to make sure - you want your users (other developers) to write type X and the compiler to compile type Y, am I right?

Comment: Essentially. I am hoping there is another mechanism in WPF that I am not aware of that would achieve the same notion.

Comment: One thing that I can think of is to create a Visual Studio Extension that finds and substitutes all tags in a given file. That extension then can be automatically run at each Save operation on the file. [But I must say - this sounds extremely confusing for your users. Any developer should know exactly what will their code do. Hidden substitution is usually "evil".]